# Align columns with other section and elements in row

Tags: angularjs, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with aligning text in a single row I tried using Fexl approach as well as other approaches as well

```
also some of the data in my div is rendered dynamically using ng-repeat 

the third column displays special data always.

all the rows from 3 columns should be aligned equally 

please help me

link for plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/LSLktvmvlaQtWUofzJvF?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question - I ran into a similar problem on another project, and I ended up giving each div a fixed height and setting the overflow to hidden. It takes a bit of testing, but if you're aiming for a responsive design, you can uses Sass to set it to different heights based on screen resolution.

Adding this CSS to your Plunkr would be a good starting point. Of course, you'd want to apply this to a custom class and not '.col-md-6':

```
.col-md-6 {
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Increase the 'height' as needed to make sure all text fits.

Comment: as the data is dynamic and can be of any size if we fix the height it would not be a good practise